# Undefined index in Wordpress plugin when call AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I created plugin for Wordpress and am now trying to learn [Ajax in plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

When I call my function:

```
wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_action
```

I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: whatever

This is my function

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' ); // Write our JS below here

function my_action_javascript() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var data = {
            'action': 'my_action',
            'whatever': 1234
        };
        // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        });
    });
    </script> <?php
}
```

and function call back

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database
    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );
    $whatever += 10;
        echo $whatever;
    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

What's causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a request to `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_action` it only includes the `action` query string parameter and not the `whatever` parameter that the callback function in WordPress is expecting.

If you want this to work in a browser test from the address bar replace `$_POST['whatever']` with `$_REQUEST['whatever']` and use this in your browser `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_action&whatever=1234` - this will pass `whatever` as a `GET` whereas in your ajax it is a `POST`, but `$_REQUEST` will see both.

That said, your example code is correct - I even tested it on a local install. When your JavaScript executes it will include both parameters as part of the `data` object, which can then be process in the ajax handler. Just load your site in a browser and the code should alert unless you have other JavaScript errors.